# How can I fix my code and change glyphicon on click for a toggle menu

Tags: jquery, html

I made a button and the purpose of it is to toggle a menu when the screen is small. I have everything working, when I click the icon to toggle "menu hamburger" it expands and shows an X instead of a menu hamburger, and vice versa. The problem comes when I click the icon fast multiple times in a row, from what I can tell the toggle doesn't go with the icon. I would like to, when the screen is little, show the menu icon (it does this right), and when I click it it should expand the other options as well as the icon change to the X. So basically connect the menu and the icon so the icons don't get ahead of themselves. I feel like my problem is in the jQuery but I am not sure what it is or how i can have these two work simultaneously. I have this toggle button on a bootstrap navbar Thank you!

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('#togglebtt').on('click', function () {
        $(this).find('span').toggleClass('glyphicon-menu-hamburger').toggleClass('glyphicon-remove');
            });
        });
```

and below its my button

```
<button  id="togglebtt" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" class="navbar-toggle collapsed">
    <span class="glyphic glyphicon-menu-hamburger"></span></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a little longer, but should be more consistent:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('#togglebtt').on('click', function () {
       if ($(this).find('span').hasClass('glyphicon-menu-hamburger')) {
         $(this).removeClass('glyphicon-menu-hamburger')
                .addClass('glyphicon-remove');
       } else {
         $(this).removeClass('glyphicon-remove')
                .addClass('glyphicon-menu-hamburger');
       }
    });
});
```

Edit:

Also, see this Fiddle for an alternate method (FontAwesome rather than glyphicons): http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/t763P/